# Can anyone explain step by how to add product to CART using REST API?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, addtocart, rest-api, shopping-cart

I tried this link http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/ - But not able to understand what exactly to do?

Please help me.

Comment: may be there is no api for add to cart in magento 1.x but you can create your own api

Comment: @GopalPatel - hmm, Do you know how to create api?

Comment: refer http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_extend_magento_rest_api.html

Comment: for rest it is available have a look http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html

Comment: @Magento2Learner - That link refer to SOAP api.

Comment: Yes I know that if your aim is to achieve the functionality then you can do this by soap instead of developing custom API in rest.

Comment: Its my typo "for rest " not but "for SOAP"

Comment: @Magento2Learner - I  added product to cart successfully. But the product is not visible in cart page. Do you know why it happened? In table it got successfuly added.

Comment: Try to get product from cart with api and display there ? or else let me know how you are testing it ?

Comment: @Magento2Learner - To see cart product I have added code - $result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart_product.list', '15');

Comment: what result you are getting in this ?

Comment: @Magento2Learner - Result - array(0) {}

Comment: Please refer the document you need to send cart or quote id so in that quote whatever product will be added magento will return

Answer (score 0):

Hi Below is the code for add simple product running code  ::

Add Simple Product To Cart ::

```
URL ::<<YOUR URL >>/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer {TOKEN_ID}
REQUEST BODY ::
{
  "cart_item": {
    "quote_id": 2470,
    "sku": "59331563",
    "qty": 1
  }
}

RESPONSE ::
{
  "item_id": 17778,
  "sku": "59331563",
  "qty": 1,
  "name": "Physics XII art II  Class-12  NCERT1",
  "price": 0,
  "product_type": "simple",
  "quote_id": "2470"
}
```

Comment: is this code for magento 1.9 ?

Comment: @Taslim Waris - Can you explain me little more detail?

Comment: above Code is for magento 2

Comment: @GopalPatel Yes I am just confirming it.